# C++ Binary search using SIMD

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, c++20, simd

Recently I found that the binary search (`std::ranges::lower_bound` and `std::ranges::upper_bound`) is the main bottleneck in my library.

So I wanted to improve it, one attempt was to use SIMD to replace the C++ standard library binary search. In short, the result was actually little bit slower than original binary search.

But I don't want to just discard it away, so I upload it here.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename K>
concept CanUseSimd = (sizeof(K) == 4 || sizeof(K) == 8) && (std::signed_integral<K> || std::floating_point<K>);

using regi = __m512i;
using regf = __m512;
using regd = __m512d;

unsigned int cmp(std::int32_t key, const std::int32_t* key_ptr) {
    regi key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_epi32(key);
    regi keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_si512(reinterpret_cast<const regi*>(key_ptr));
    return _mm512_cmpgt_epi32_mask(key_broadcasted, keys_to_comp);
}

unsigned int cmp(std::int64_t key, const std::int64_t* key_ptr) {
    regi key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_epi64(key);
    regi keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_si512(reinterpret_cast<const regi*>(key_ptr));
    return _mm512_cmpgt_epi64_mask(key_broadcasted, keys_to_comp);
}

unsigned int cmp(float key, const float* key_ptr) {
    regf key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_ps(key);
    regf keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_ps(key_ptr);
    return _mm512_cmp_ps_mask(key_broadcasted, keys_to_comp, _MM_CMPINT_GT);
}

unsigned int cmp(double key, const double* key_ptr) {
    regd key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_pd(key);
    regd keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_pd(key_ptr);
    return _mm512_cmp_pd_mask(key_broadcasted, keys_to_comp, _MM_CMPINT_GT);
}

unsigned int cmp(const std::int32_t* key_ptr, std::int32_t key) {
    regi key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_epi32(key);
    regi keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_si512(reinterpret_cast<const regi*>(key_ptr));
    return _mm512_cmpgt_epi32_mask(keys_to_comp, key_broadcasted);
}

unsigned int cmp(const std::int64_t* key_ptr, std::int64_t key) {
    regi key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_epi64(key);
    regi keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_si512(reinterpret_cast<const regi*>(key_ptr));
    return _mm512_cmpgt_epi64_mask(keys_to_comp, key_broadcasted);
}

unsigned int cmp(const float* key_ptr, float key) {
    regf key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_ps(key);
    regf keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_ps(key_ptr);
    return _mm512_cmp_ps_mask(keys_to_comp, key_broadcasted, _MM_CMPINT_GT);
}

unsigned int cmp(const double* key_ptr, double key) {
    regd key_broadcasted = _mm512_set1_pd(key);
    regd keys_to_comp = _mm512_load_pd(key_ptr);
    return _mm512_cmp_pd_mask(keys_to_comp, key_broadcasted, _MM_CMPINT_GT);
}

template <CanUseSimd K>
struct SimdTrait {
    static constexpr int shift = (sizeof(K) == 4) ? 4 : 3;
    static constexpr int mask = (sizeof(K) == 4) ? 0xF : 0x7;
    static constexpr int unit = (sizeof(K) == 4) ? 16 : 8;
};

template <CanUseSimd K, bool less>
inline std::int32_t get_lb_simd(K key, const K* first, const K* last) {
    auto len = static_cast<std::int32_t>(last - first);
    // make to the least multiple of SimdUnit which is at least len
    len = ((len >> SimdTrait<K>::shift) + ((len & SimdTrait<K>::mask) ? 1 : 0)) << SimdTrait<K>::shift;

    const K* curr = first;
    std::int32_t i = 0;
    int mask = 0;
    auto half = (len >> (SimdTrait<K>::shift + 1)) << SimdTrait<K>::shift;
    while (len > SimdTrait<K>::unit) {
        len -= half;
        auto next_half = (len >> (SimdTrait<K>::shift + 1)) << SimdTrait<K>::shift;
        __builtin_prefetch(curr + next_half - SimdTrait<K>::unit);
        __builtin_prefetch(curr + half + next_half - SimdTrait<K>::unit);
        auto mid = curr + half - SimdTrait<K>::unit;
        if constexpr (less) {
            mask = ~cmp(key, mid);
        } else {
            mask = ~cmp(mid, key);
        }
        i = __builtin_ffs(mask) - 1;
        curr += (i == SimdTrait<K>::unit) * half;
        if (i & SimdTrait<K>::mask) {
            return static_cast<std::int32_t>(mid - first) + i;
        }
        half = next_half;
    }
    if constexpr (less) {
        mask = ~cmp(key, curr);
    } else {
        mask = ~cmp(curr, key);
    }
    i = __builtin_ffs(mask) - 1;
    return std::min(static_cast<std::int32_t>(last - first), static_cast<std::int32_t>(curr - first) + i);
}

template <CanUseSimd K, bool less>
inline std::int32_t get_ub_simd(K key, const K* first, const K* last) {
    auto len = static_cast<std::int32_t>(last - first);
    // make to the least multiple of SimdUnit which is at least len
    len = ((len >> SimdTrait<K>::shift) + ((len & SimdTrait<K>::mask) ? 1 : 0)) << SimdTrait<K>::shift;

    const K* curr = first;
    std::int32_t i = 0;
    int mask = 0;
    while (len > SimdTrait<K>::unit) {
        auto half = (len >> (SimdTrait<K>::shift + 1)) << SimdTrait<K>::shift;
        len -= half;
        auto mid = curr + half - SimdTrait<K>::unit;
        if constexpr (less) {
            mask = cmp(mid, key);
        } else {
            mask = cmp(key, mid);
        }
        i = __builtin_ffs(mask) - 1;
        curr += (mask == 0) * half;
        if (i > 0) {
            return static_cast<std::int32_t>(mid - first) + i;
        }
    }
    if constexpr (less) {
        mask = cmp(curr, key);
    } else {
        mask = cmp(key, curr);
    }
    i = (mask == 0) ? len : __builtin_ffs(mask) - 1;
    return std::min(static_cast<std::int32_t>(last - first), static_cast<std::int32_t>(curr - first) + i);
}
```

Comment: The MD-angle seems to escape me: Can I access a description of the algorithm these lower&upper bound functions implement - how does binary search on multiple data work? Did I see 8/16 consecutive haystack values compared to the same needle, with a return guaranteed once `len` < `SimdTrait<K>::unit`? (Isn't it a pity to broadcast the same needle over and again?)

Comment: @greybeard This is tested to be correct, but yes, broadcasting the same needle over and over again was foolish. I'll test it right after I get back from work

Comment: Ideas for main reason why a faster binary search may not be the most effective way to reduce total processing time: a) finding the index of *key* in an ordered index isn't the optimal approach for the larger problem b) *index for key* is called avoidably often. Consider a separate question about (your solution to) the larger problem.

Comment: Ideas why the code presented fails to improve binary search: a) (lack of) cache alignment - transferring 512 bits at once is more likely to straddle a cache line boundary than 64 or 32 bits b) using parallel comparisons while the chances of hitting the boundary between ≤ and ≥ is slim - they look favourable only from 3*512 bits and below c) overhead for small arrays

Comment: @greybeard I'm actually using SIMD linear search now (not SIMD binary search), (my use case is array size <= 256) and I see SIMD outperforms my previous implementation, so I switched to that

Answer (score 3):

## Use the same API as `std::ranges::lower_bound`

You mention that you wanted to use `std::ranges` algorithms to do a binary search. If you implement your own functions, try to keep the same interface as the standard library does. This allows your functions to be used as drop-in replacements for the STL ones, making porting the code easier.

The STL algorithms either get passed two iterators or a range. You can use the [`std::contiguous_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator) concept to restrict those iterators to ones that are suitable for SIMD operations.

I would also make sure your function names match those of the STL, but put them in your own namespace. This way, you can write:

```
std::vector<int> data;
...
auto result = simd::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 42);
```

And if you were using `using namespace std::ranges` before, you can simply add or change that to `using namespace simd` without having to change any calls to `lower_bound()`, and even better: since you are using concepts, this can be made to transparently fall back to the `std::ranges` versions for types that are not supported by your SIMD versions.

You'll also notice that the STL either returns iterators or `std::size_t` values. Don't cast lengths and indices to `std::uint32_t`; it will not give you any speedup and it might result in incorrectly working code if someone wants to run it on arrays larger than 4 gigabytes.

Most STL algorithms that need to compare elements of a container use [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) by default, and allow you to pass a custom comparator. Again, just follow this pattern, but make SIMD versions, so that your `lower_bound()` looks like:

```
namespace simd {

template<CanUseSimd T>
struct less;

template<CanUseSimd T>
struct greater;

template<>
struct less<std::int32_t> {
    unsigned int operator()(std::int32_t* data, std::int32_t key) {
        regi keys   = _mm512_set1_epi32(key);
        regi values = _mm512_load_si512(reinterpret_cast<const regi*>(data));
        return _mm512_cmplt_epi32_mask(keys, values);
    }
};

template<>
struct greater<std::int32_t> {
    unsigned int operator()(std::int32_t* data, std::int32_t key) {
        ...
        return _mm512_cmpgt_epi32_mask(keys, values);
    }
};

...

template<std::contiguous_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S, class T, class Comp = less>
requires CanUseSimd<I::value_type>
I lower_bound(I first, S last, const T& value, Comp comp = {});

}
```

## Use the C++ standard library where possible

The [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) has lots of functionality, and with every new release of the standard, more is added. Nowadays it is rare that you have to fall back to C functions. Consider `__builtin_ffs()`: since C++20, you can now use [`std::countr_zero()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero).

To find the halfway point between to values, or even two pointers, there's [`std::midpoint()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint). Consider creating your own SIMD version of it:

```
template<CanUseSimd K>
const K* midpoint(const K* a, const K* b) {
    auto len = b - a;
    auto half = (len / 2) & ~SimdTrait<K>::mask;
    return a + half;
}
```

## Prefetching might not be worth it

I notice you are using `__builtin_prefetch()` in `get_lb_simd()`, but not in `get_ub_simd()`. You are also fetching two cachelines: one for the lower half, and one for the upper half. But you'll only use one of those. Thus, you are using twice as much memory bandwidth as necessary. The latency of the AVX-512 mask compare instructions is only 3 according to the [Intel® Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm512_cmp_&techs=AVX_512), so while prefetching the right cacheline might hide a little bit of latency, prefetching the wrong one as well will probably negate any benefit. Then again, it heavily depends on the microarchitecture and the memory system, so you will have to benchmark it with and without prefetching to see what the impact is.

## Consider using a SIMD library

Using intrinsics has some drawbacks: apart from making it hard to port your code to other CPU architectures like Arm, you have to write a lot of code yourself. Consider using a C++ library that provides you with the same functionality, but in a generic way, like [Google Highway](https://github.com/google/highway). This should simplify your own code considerably.